# VB Script to Delete Desktop shortcut

Tags: vbscript

I need help with this script.  This script creates a new desktop shortcut and then deletes another one.  However I want it to delete one desktop shortcut if it exists or another if it exists.  Not sure how to do this.  I've put the 2 different shortcuts in after the "fso.deletefile" but I'm not sure what syntax to use (how to word it.)  I'm new to vbs. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
L_Welcome_MsgBox_Message_Text = "A shortcut to the PM Master" & vbcrlf & "will be created on your desktop."
L_Welcome_MsgBox_Title_Text ="Windows Scripting Host Sample"

Call Welcome()

Dim WSHShell
Set WSHShell =CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim MyShortcut, MyDesktop, DesktopPath
' Read desktop path using WshSpecialFolders object
DesktopPath =WSHShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
' Create a shortcut object on the desktop
Set MyShortcut =WSHShell.CreateShortcut(DesktopPath & "\PM-Master-ALL.lnk")
' Set shortcut object properties and save it
MyShortcut.TargetPath =WSHShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings( "c:\Local Cloud\Shared\Sites\Bailey Lane\PM-Master-ALL")
MyShortcut.Save
Set Shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
DesktopPath = Shell.SpecialFolders("Desktop")
FSO.DeleteFile DesktopPath & "\PM Master - ALL.lnk"
FSO.DeleteFile DesktopPath & "\PM Master - ALL -  Shortcut.lnk"


WScript.Echo "A shortcut to the PM Master has been successfully created. The older PM Master shortcut has been deleted."

Sub Welcome()
    Dim intDoIt
    intDoIt = MsgBox(L_Welcome_MsgBox_Message_Text, vbOKCancel + vbInformation, L_Welcome_MsgBox_Title_Text )
    If intDoIt = vbCancel Then
    WScript.Quit

End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x23stk5t%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). You can use the `FileExists` method to check whether a file exists before attempting to delete it:

```
shortcut = DesktopPath & "\PM Master - ALL.lnk"
If FSO.FileExists(shortcut) Then FSO.DeleteFile shortcut
```

Comment: For some reason the C:\Users\Public\Desktop\my shortcut.lnk isn't deleting...